# Symfony form data are not formatted to camelCase

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a simple form with Symfony version 3.4.

I just created a Client type for the form, a Client controller to handle the creation of the client and a Client entity.

This is the code for the buildForm method:

```
        $builder->add('firstName', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Add Client'])
        ;
```

This is the Client entity code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }
```

the form is displayed correctly and when I submit it the data are passed this way by the client:

```
client[firstName]   Mario
client[lastName]    Rossi
client[save]    
client[_token]  3cqO2C63eLhKrcBdvSYgyT5qXwNBVL7T5fYvhGWRkYQ
```

but when I var_dump the object coming from the `$form->getData()` in the controller handler I get this array:

```
object(App\Entity\Client)#385 (5) { ["id":"App\Entity\Client":private]=> NULL ["firstName":"App\Entity\Client":private]=> NULL ["lastName":"App\Entity\Client":private]=> NULL ["firstname"]=> string(5) "Mario" ["lastname"]=> string(5) "Rossi" }
```

As you can see the camelCased keys are NULL but the data are stored within non camelCased keys instead (firstname and lastname) and so I receive error from Doctrine/SQL complaining about columns cannot be NULL.

Any clue on this one? Thanks.

Comment: `private` - means private.

Comment: That is because the entities attributes are only modified by their own set methods and not directly. That is why they are set private. Should not be related with the non camelcased keys in my opinion.

Comment: Well I don't use symphony and I have no idea what `$builder->add('firstName', TextType::class)` does,  for example `function add($key, $value){ $key = strtolower($key); .... }` etc...  I think relying on casing is asking for problems, besides the confusion it will cause.

Comment: No problem thanks for the try. The problem is still there even when I try with first_name in `$builder->add('first_name`, TextType::class)` the controller still receive from the client 'firstname'. (by the way in Symfony $builder is the helper to build a form before it gets displayed in the view).

Comment: If you're using the entity as a form data object, it should be using PropertyAccessor, which actually doesn't work with private properties. See: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/23938

Comment: Some more documentation on PropertyAccessor: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/property_access.html Can you post the entity code? PropertyAccessor tries to be intelligent, but sometimes it fails to recognize getters/setters.

Comment: I've already tried to convert all the properties of the Client entity to `public` but the keys coming along with the $form->getData method are still wrong

Comment: That's weird... Are you using any form events to modify data?

Comment: No it's a very basic example actually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192069/discussion-between-kal-zekdor-and-user2861867).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the chat discussion, the code was linked in full and I noticed a typo in both the setters:

```
public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
{
    $this->firstname = $firstName; 
    //          ^ should be a capital N

    return $this
}
```

and the same for the `setLastName`